# Android overriding onBackPress unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, viewflipper

Yet another problem whilst trying to create the UI for an app.

I've got a Viewflipper in a tab which slides from View 1 to View 2 to View 3. I've overridden the onBackPress method to navigate back to a previous view if I am not on View 1.

It works fine when on View 2, pressing back goes to View 1.
But when on View 3, pressing back ends the Tab activity and takes me back to the sign in activity.

Here's a video in case my description was hard to understand: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nKhgpq3rQA

Has anyone come across anything similar?
Why does the onBackPress get ignored in my Tab Activity when View 3 is displayed? I've debugged and put a breakpoint on the onBackPressed method in my Tab Activity, the breakpoint is hit in all cases except for when View 3 is the shown view. Werid.

Thanks for your time.

**Update:** I've discovered that if I add another ListView as the View 3 it works, but if I add a TextView as View 3 it doesn't behave as expected, crazy.

Comment: It's a bad hard to since there's other stuff and it'll take awhile to delete that stuff. I could perhaps make a demo project if no one can help.

Comment: So I'm experiencing the same problem, but not with a ViewFlipper, but an ActivityGroup.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174624/back-button-behavior-with-tabs-and-activitygroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, there was some weird behaviour because I was adding the first view in my view flipper to the tab content, rather than adding the viewflipper itself.

Answer (score 0):

just don't call super.onBackPressed(); then you can handle every back click your self. 
calling super.onBackPressed(); will get to the activity called before.

Comment: As mentioned, when back is pressed when View 3 is displayed the breakpoint I set on the overridden onBackPressed isn't even hit, I don't even enter it. The app goes to some other onBackPressed handler.