# Back button behavior with tabs and ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-tabhost, back, activitygroup

I have an Activity (`Main`) which shows tabs like this:

```
private void initTabs(){
    mTabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost

    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyGroup.class);
    setupTab(intent, "tab");
}

private void setupTab(Intent intent, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText)).setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

The `MyGroup` class is an ActivityGroup, which does the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activityA", new Intent(this, ActivityA.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
    this.setContentView(view);

            state = A;
}

public void openB() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activityB", i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
    this.setContentView(view);
            state = B;
}
```

So `Main` has a tab with a `MyGroup`. The `MyGroup` starts with `ActivityA` and then goes to `ActivityB`. When I press the back button in `ActivityB`, I want to go back to `ActivityA`, and on back press in `ActivityA` I want to close the app.

This is how I've done that. In `ActivityB`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("ActivityB PRESSED");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        MyGroup mg = (MyGroup) getParent();
        return mg.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

In `ActivityA` the same:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ActivityA PRESSED");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            MyGroup mg = (MyGroup) getParent();
            return mg.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Now, in `MyGroup`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            System.out.println("MG PRESSED");   
                if (state == A)
                return false;
            else if (state == B) {
            setContentView(getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activityA", new Intent(this, ActivityA.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView());
                state = A;
                return true;
        }

        return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Finally, in `Main`, just a system.out:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("MAIN PRESSED");
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Now this is my current behavior, which I don't want:

- When app started, I'm in ActivityA. Backbutton -> app closes. OK.
- When app started, ActivityA -> ActivityB -> Back button -> ActivityA. OK.
- When app started, ActivityA -> ActivityB -> Back -> ActivityA ->
  ActivityB -> Back -> app closes. NOT OK!

Apparently, the second time ActivityB is shown, the back button is being handled by `Main`, instead of `ActivityB` or `MyGroup`.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I've added an ActivityC. It seems like behaviour in the first two activities is normal, and from the third on, the `Main` activity handles the button press.

So A -> B -> A is handled by A -> B -> Main

and A -> B -> C is handled by A -> B -> Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer.

I have an admob adview in my `Main`, which seems the cause of this problem. This is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
                    android:padding="0dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/adkey"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:focusable="false"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/adView"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

When I remove the adview, the problem doesn't occur.

Now to solve this, I've changed the xml into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/adkey"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:focusable="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `public void onBackPressed()` in your activity and handle the back button click yourself. 
Calling `super.onBackPressed();` will affect the standard behaviour of back button press (also exit your app)

Comment: Using `onKeyDown` or `onBackPressed` yields the same effect.